# Python converting txt in array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, file, samba

I'm reading a .dat file from a samba file server that contains some wind sensor data. That file contains a header with some information (lines 1,3 and 4), a line with sensors names on it (2nd line), and the reading of sensors on the body (144 lines, 1 line each 10 minutes), like this:

```
"DataFormat","Anemometric tower","Datalogger","SomeCode","LoggerOS","LoggerFileSystem","AnotherCode","Table1"
"TIMESTAMP","RECORD","Precipit1","Barometer1","Temperature1","Humidity1","Anemometer1","Windvane1","Anemometer2","Windvane2","Battery1"
"TS","RN","","hPa","C. Deg","%RH","m/s","Deg","m/s","Deg","Volts"
"","","Smp","Avg","Avg","Avg","Avg","Avg","Avg","Avg","Avg"
"2019-06-19 00:10:00",1211,"NAN",921.014,19.57733,98.29526,10.76701,137.6863,10.68348,139.7062,11.91,
"2019-06-19 00:20:00",1212,"NAN",920.9402,19.44474,98.67733,9.991986,141.5792,9.892648,143.3559,11.35
"2019-06-19 00:30:00",1213,"NAN",920.6142,19.45635,99.00026,10.80979,148.0094,10.63116,150.0893,11.41
...more 141 lines...
```

My goal is to convert the raw text into a table (so for example, I know all values from column 4 belongs to Barometer1 sensor).

I managed to do a PHP script that works, I read all file until end of file, append to a string, explode with EOL delimiter (result array of lines), then finally explode with ',' (comma) delimiter (array of array?)

```php
       $data = '';
       while (!feof($stream)) {
           $data .= fread($stream, 8192);
       }
       $lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $data);
       foreach ($lines as $line) {
           $array[] = explode(",", $line);
       }
```

Then I loop throught $array[$row][$col], make a list for each type of sensor and insert each list on respective database table.

But I need this to work with **python** script, so I tried

```py
    data = file_obj.read()
    file_obj.close()    

    lines = data.split('\n')
    array = []
    for line in lines:
        array[lines.index(line)] = line.split(',')
```

Printing **data** on terminal return the full text in string, printing **lines** on terminal return each line (ex: print(lines[1])) while **array** return error

```
    array[lines.index(line)] = line.split(',')
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Working with [pysmb](https://pysmb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/smb_SMBConnection.html) library to get file_obj from samba share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this purpose, its better to use python pandas library to organize the data in a dataframe.

e.g

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('yourfile.dat',
            header=None, sep='\s\s+', engine='python')
```

Comment: Im learning about pandas now. This library can help me inserting data on database? If no, there's a reason to me adding another program layer to it?

I ask that, because in my head, my task is: read file > organize table rows into lists (ex: anemometer1List= ['2019-06-19 00:10:00' => 10.76701, '2019-06-19 00:20:00' => 9.991986]...), > insert list in database.

If I use pandas, I should read file > organize data > insert in pandas dataframe > insert dataframe in database

Comment: Yes you can directly insert df into a database. You can google as per your database. 
e.g df.to_sql('table', engine, if_exists='replace')

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution is to turn your rows into lists and append them to a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

list=[["DataFormat","Anemometric tower","Datalogger","SomeCode","LoggerOS","LoggerFileSystem","AnotherCode","Table1"]]

df=pd.DataFrame(list,columns=['col1'])
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to program a similar logic (both php and python), I managed to make it work using [append](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_append.asp)
function.

But, like people has mentioned, panda library can help aswell.

```py
data = file_obj.read()
file_obj.close()    

lines = data.split('\n')
array = []
for line in lines:
    array.append(line.split(','))
```